# Why is there an "o" in "controversus"?

Tags: etymology, phonology, prefix

Apparently, *[contrōversus](https://books.google.com/books?id=C4E1AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA377&lpg=PA377&dq=Latin%20contra%20controversus&source=bl&ots=QGZBtAJ8ek&sig=riR8Sd7D7AFSFlS8pvp6e4Tl_yQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXosnPisbMAhWMHT4KHRh2CLQQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=Latin%20contra%20controversus&f=false)* comes from the preposition *contrā-* + *versus.* So why does it have "ō" instead of "ā"? I checked [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=controversus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), but it doesn't explain the development of this vowel. I also found that [*contrāversus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontraversus) does in fact exist, although it seems to have a different meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as we have both *intrā* and *intrō*, *citrā/citrō, ultrā/ultrō*, there used to be a form *contrō*, which has only survived in this word. De Vaan adduces an Oscan form *contrud*. Historically, the -ō forms are masc./neut. ablatives, the -ā forms are fem. ablatives.

Comment: Interesting! But, I still find this a bit confusing: what nouns are these ablatives of? And is it known why the feminine form ended up being more commonly used? Wiktionary lists nouns that seem to correspond to some of them, but not all ([exter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exter#Latin), [ulter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ulter), [citer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/citer)). Surprisingly to me, "exter" seems to have the stem "exter-" rather than "extr-."

Comment: @sumelic They're ablatives of "comparatives" in _*-tero-_. Scare quotes because these aren't normal comparatives of adjectives, but have the older PIE function of specifying "one of a pair" (inner as opposed to outer, etc.). Presumably the feminine forms imply some understood feminine noun that is being modified -- *pars*, maybe?